# How to close and reopen a form from another form?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, callback

I have a list box with a list of employees and when the event of `selected index changed` is called a new form opens with some employee info such as email, name, location. But when another user is clicked I want the previous form to close and open the new selected employee.

This is the current code I am using to try and close the form and then reopen it, but I am getting an error with the dispose call:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: 
"Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'EmployeeInfoPopup'.
```

The code is inside of the event `EmployeeListBox_SelectedIndexChanged`.

```
EmployeeInfoPopup popup = new EmployeeInfoPopup();
if(popup.Enabled == true)
{
     popup.Dispose();
     popup.employeePopupLayout(employeeListBox.SelectedIndex);
     popup.Show();
}
else
{
     popup.employeePopupLayout(employeeListBox.SelectedIndex);
     popup.Show();
}
```

This is the method that is called in the `EmployeeInfoPopup` Form

```
public void employeePopupLayout(int currentEmployeeIndex)
{
     SeatingChart_2_0 seatingChart = new SeatingChart_2_0();
     employeeLabel.Text = ($"Name: {seatingChart.employeesNames[currentEmployeeIndex]}\nEmail: {seatingChart.employeesEmails[currentEmployeeIndex]}\nBuilding: {seatingChart.employeesBID[currentEmployeeIndex]}\nFloor: {seatingChart.employeesFID[currentEmployeeIndex]}\nSeat: {seatingChart.employeesSID[currentEmployeeIndex]}");
}
```

Comment: `I am getting an error with the dispose call`, please post this error, maybe stack trace would be helpful? My best guess is you are `disposing` the `popup` instance if it's enabled, *but* then you are trying to access `employeePopupLayout` and you can't because you disposed of the object...

Comment: Consider not using instance after disposal.

Comment: `popup.Dispose()` means "i'm ***throwing this away***, disposing of it, getting rid of it, not using it any more, I'm done with it, I promise I will never use it again". Don't just call random methods without finding out what they do. They do things, all of them. Find out what things they do before calling them.

Comment: So would there be a way for me to close the popup, but not dispose it?  Do I need to call the popup.show() before the call for employeePopupLayout?

Comment: @SauerweinB Call `popup.Hide()`.

Comment: @EdPlunkett 'popup.Hide()' does not seem to be working it still leaves the previous popup open from the previously selected employee and opens a new one with the newly selected employee.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If instance is `Dispose`d

```
 popup.Dispose();
```

you can't opened it any more (all required resources like `Handle` are *released*)

```
 popup.Show(); // <- Will throw exception
```

You can try to find out if there's *opened* `EmployeeInfoPopup` form (and `Close` it):

```
  using System.Linq;

  ... 

  // Close the last opened EmployeeInfoPopup if it exists
  Application
    .OpenForms
    .OfType<EmployeeInfoPopup>()
    .LastOrDefault()
   ?.Close();
```

If you want to delete *all* such forms:

```
   var forms = Application
      .OpenForms
      .OfType<EmployeeInfoPopup>()
      .ToArray();

   foreach (var form in forms)
     form.Close();
```

And then create and open a new `EmployeeInfoPopup` istance

```
  // Create a new EmployeeInfoPopup instance
  EmployeeInfoPopup popup = new EmployeeInfoPopup(); 

  popup.employeePopupLayout(employeeListBox.SelectedIndex);
  popup.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this pattern:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

static private Dictionary<int, EmployeeInfoPopup> EmployeeInfoForms 
  = new Dictionary<int, EmployeeInfoPopup>();

private void EmployeeListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int index = EmployeeListBox.SelectedIndex;
  if ( EmployeeInfoForms.ContainsKey(index) )
  {
    EmployeeInfoForms[index].Close();
  }
  else
  {
    EmployeeInfoPopup popup = new EmployeeInfoPopup();
    EmployeeInfoForms.Add(index, popup);
    popup.employeePopupLayout(index);
    popup.Show();
  }
}

static internal void EmployeeInfoPopupClosed(EmployeeInfoPopup sender)
{
  var key = EmployeeInfoForms.FirstOrDefault(v => v.Value == sender).Key;
  if ( key != null )
    EmployeeInfoForms.Remove(key);
}
```

We use a dictionary of opened EmployeeInfoPopup keyed by the listbox item index.

This let you have multiple forms opened same time if you change the `Close` by a `Show`.

Then we check if the form is already created to close (or show) it or to create, initialize and open it.

On the `FormClosed` event of the `EmployeeInfoPopup`, add:

```
TheFormWithTheListBoxClassName.EmployeeInfoPopupClosed(this);
```

This works fine if you have only one instance of TheFormWithTheListBoxClassName, else more code is needed to manage the instances using a dictionary of the previous dictianary keyed by TheFormWithTheListBoxClassName.

Let me know your case and I'll update the code.